# script not found error while using new template based on the postgresql-persistent template

Tags: openshift

Hi i'm trying to follow the sequence in https://www.openshift.com/blog/deploy-postgresql-in-openshift-backed-by-openshift-container-storage.

I'm trying to do the following Run the `oc create` command and firstly run the 
script to create the new template based on postgresql template

$ bash **create_ocs_postgresql_template** 
bash: create_ocs_postgresql_template: No such file or directory 
It is giving the result as not found .. ">"what is missing here ?">" 
I'm using Git bash terminal and using OC client command to connect to OpenShift
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The guide seems to be outdated. Commit [5720e9b](https://github.com/red-hat-storage/ocs-training/commit) is when RedHat deleted the ocs4postgresql directory which contained the create_ocs_postgresql_template. So if you'd like to access the script, checkout master before the [5720e9b](https://github.com/red-hat-storage/ocs-training/commit) commit. For instance, [af185a7](https://github.com/red-hat-storage/ocs-training/tree/af185a70e02858f55e16819d89d5fb3274f782f6)  still contains the [create_ocs_postgresql_template](https://github.com/red-hat-storage/ocs-training/blob/af185a70e02858f55e16819d89d5fb3274f782f6/ocs4postgresql/create_ocs_postgresql_template).

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks. I'm now trying to simply recreating the file without checking out a certain commit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in correct directory? List files and check where is "create_ocs_postgresql_template "

Comment: Could you elaborate it , i'm connected to open shift using the client CLI , i believe there are no such commands to infer the presence of a script.
Could you please point out the command ?

Comment: This script must be somehere locally.  In instruction I see "Please git clone this repository, you’ll find all the scripts needed in the ocs4jenkins directory:" but in git I doesn't see any scripts that are named like "create_ocs_postgresql_template". Maybe there is something wrong with this training.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Though the article is elaborate however the weakest point is the initial setup. The idea is not to further deep delve into postgres but kicking the postges container deploy in openshift. It seems to me the commands are run from the cluster terminal using what ever needed privileges. However such things should be discouraged as the thrust is on the CLI to do multifarious tasks.